# Spark Dataframe Group by having New Indicator Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to group by "KEY" Column and need to check whether "TYPE_CODE" column has both "PL" and "JL" values , if so then i need to add a Indicator Column as "Y" else "N"

Example :

```
    //Input Values
    val values = List(List("66","PL") ,
    List("67","JL") , List("67","PL"),List("67","PO"),
    List("68","JL"),List("68","PO")).map(x =>(x(0), x(1)))

    import spark.implicits._
    //created a dataframe
    val cmc = values.toDF("KEY","TYPE_CODE")

    cmc.show(false)
    ------------------------
    KEY |TYPE_CODE  |
    ------------------------
    66  |PL |
    67  |JL |
    67  |PL |
    67  |PO |
    68  |JL |
    68  |PO |
    -------------------------
```

Expected Output :

For each "KEY", If it has "TYPE_CODE" has both PL & JL then Y
else N

```
    -----------------------------------------------------
    KEY |TYPE_CODE  | Indicator
    -----------------------------------------------------
    66  |PL         | N
    67  |JL         | Y
    67  |PL         | Y
    67  |PO         | Y
    68  |JL         | N
    68  |PO         | N
    ---------------------------------------------------
```

For example,
67 has both PL & JL - So "Y"
66 has only PL - So "N"
68 has only JL - So "N"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option:

1) collect *TYPE_CODE* as list;

2) check if it contains the specific strings;

3) then flatten the list with `explode`:

```
(cmc.groupBy("KEY")
    .agg(collect_list("TYPE_CODE").as("TYPE_CODE"))
    .withColumn("Indicator", 
        when(array_contains($"TYPE_CODE", "PL") && array_contains($"TYPE_CODE", "JL"), "Y").otherwise("N"))
    .withColumn("TYPE_CODE", explode($"TYPE_CODE"))).show
+---+---------+---------+
|KEY|TYPE_CODE|Indicator|
+---+---------+---------+
| 68|       JL|        N|
| 68|       PO|        N|    
| 67|       JL|        Y|
| 67|       PL|        Y|
| 67|       PO|        Y|
| 66|       PL|        N|
+---+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

1. Group by `KEY` and use `agg` to create two separate indicator columns (one for `JL` and on for `PL`), then calculate the combined indicator
2. `join` with the original DataFrame

Altogether:

```
val indicators = cmc.groupBy("KEY").agg(
  sum(when($"TYPE_CODE" === "PL", 1).otherwise(0)) as "pls",
  sum(when($"TYPE_CODE" === "JL", 1).otherwise(0)) as "jls"
).withColumn("Indicator", when($"pls" > 0 && $"jls" > 0, "Y").otherwise("N"))

val result = cmc.join(indicators, "KEY")
  .select("KEY", "TYPE_CODE", "Indicator")
```

This might be slower than @Psidom's answer, but might be *safer* - `collect_list` might be problematic if you have a huge number of matches for a specific key (that list would have to be stored in a single worker's memory).

**EDIT**:

In case the input is known to be *unique* (i.e. JL / PL would only appear once per key, at most), `indicators` could be created using simple `count` aggregation, which is (arguably) easier to read:

```
val indicators = cmc
  .where($"TYPE_CODE".isin("PL", "JL"))
  .groupBy("KEY").count()
  .withColumn("Indicator", when($"count" === 2, "Y").otherwise("N"))
```